# Paging animation like in Go Launcher Ex

Tags: android, animation, launcher, android-viewpager

I am using ViewPager in my application.
I can do basic paging like in Android's default launcher. Which is very easy to do.
I want to add custom animation to this paging just like in Go launcher or every other 3rd party launchers.

I have found this library
http://nineoldandroids.com/

It has rotate animations. How can I use them with viewpager?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support Library revision 11 has added this feature.

You can see

> Added PageTransformer interface to ViewPager to allow applications to supply a custom transition behavior for scrolling.

here in the link http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html